# How assign "this" object to a static class pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign the instance class to a pointer, how can I do that:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std; 

class A
{
    private:
        static A *pointer; 

    protected:

        A(){}

        A GetInstance()
        {
            //On this point throw the error: could not convert A::pointer’ from A*’ to ‘A’
            pointer& = (A)this;         
            return pointer;
        }       
};

A *A::pointer = NULL;
```

How can I do that?

```
static A *pointer;
...
...
pointer& = (A)this;
```

Is it possible? I am trying to create a simple repository class with an unique connection instantiated (only one time) and the class repository with the virtuals functions (Add, Save, GetById, GetAll()) inherit from this class, in this way I could create a lot of Repository classes using just only connection without open and close every time. If someone has a example, I would be glad.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: No, `pointer& = (A)this;` is invalid grammer. What is "assign the instance class to a pointer"? Do you mean `*pointer = *this;`?

Comment: what's with all the extra punctuation and casting? `pointer = this;` - maybe you should look up some proven singleton implementations first

Comment: @BeyelerStudios The best, industrial strength singleton implementation is "don't do it". This code has a terrible code smell.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it's a tool in your toolbox, know how and when to use it

Comment: @BeyelerStudios When the answer to "when" is "never", you don't really need to know "how".

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that's quite ignorant: how could you ever check whether or not to use it, if you didn't know what it is?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios By generalisations and analogies.. Uncontrolled, global dependencies are bad. Singleton is an uncontrolled, global dependency. No matter how it's used, created, written, designed; it introduces something you don't want. But this topic has been beaten to death already, so this is my last comment here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work as you tried because `(A)this` is a conversion from type `A *` (a pointer to an object of class `A`) to `class A` (an object of class `A`). The compiler cannot do such a conversion.

---

The type of `A::pointer` is `A *`. So is `this` inside the methods of `class A`.

All you need is:

```
pointer = this;
```

Or, if you want to make more readable, you can write:

```
A::pointer = this;
```

This way it's clear for a reader that `pointer` is a static property (class member) and not an instance property.

---

You have an error on the next line. The value returned by `A::getInstance()` (`return pointer;`) doesn't match the type declared in the method's header (an object of class `A`). The one that is wrong is the method's declaration. It doesn't make much sense to return an object of type `A`, it should return a pointer to such an object (more specifically, the only instance of the class, stored in `A::pointer`.

Change the method's definition like this:

```
A *GetInstance()
{
    pointer = this;
    return pointer;
}
```

---

As other readers already noticed in comments, it seems you are trying to implement the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (but you are only half-way through it). The best advice about Singleton is to avoid it because it is not testable. It is just a disguised global variable and global variables are, in general, a bad way to store your data.